# Theme Wordpress don´t showing contents shortcodes of plugins

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating my first theme, and it's working properly.

But when I installed 2 plugins and inserted the shortcode in my theme, nothing appears on site.

I've selected another theme and it works normally the plugins, what could be happening?

function.php

```
 <?php

require_once('inc/redux-framework-master/redux-framework.php');
require_once('inc/office-master-theme-options.php');


add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post','page' ) );

function enqueue_jquery() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery' ); 


    wp_register_script( 
         'jquery', 
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js',
         array(), 
         '1.11.1', 
         false
    );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_jquery');



function enqueue_styles_scripts() {


    wp_enqueue_style(
        'style-theme',
        get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array('bootstrap-css')
    );


    wp_enqueue_style(
        'bootstrap-css',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    );


    wp_enqueue_style(
        'stylish-portfolio',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/stylish-portfolio.css'
    );


    wp_enqueue_style(
        'font-awesome',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css'

    ); 



    wp_enqueue_script(
        'bootstrap-js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js',null
    );


} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles_scripts');



function wpse_ie_conditional_scripts() { ?>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_ie_conditional_scripts' );





require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
register_nav_menus( array(
     'primary' => __( 'Main Menu', 'THEMENAME' ),
) );


?>
```

page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="article">
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    <p><?php echo do_shortcode('[meta_gallery_slider]'); ?></p>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <div class="article">
                    <p>Error 404</p>
                </div>          
            <?php endif; ?>



        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The htmls and src tags of the gallery images appear in the console, but the screen turns white in the location that should display the images

Comment: It's very likely that your jQuery override is causing problems.  Why are you `deregistering` jQuery? Use the jQuery that comes with WP, please.  Your `page.php` template looks right, **assuming** this is the template that is being rendered when you have problems.

Comment: @cale_b The default wordpress Jquery is added to the header and the bootstrap did not work, I was not able to register another version of jquery for the bootstrap to work, so I just managed to make the bootstrap work by unregistering the default jquery. And also I could not put the default jquery on footer

Comment: I did according to your suggestion. I tried to use the default jquery, but it is not added in the header, so the plugins have not yet appeared on the page, and the bootstrap did not work either

Comment: Please be specific.  See my updates to the answer.  What do you mean "Tried to use the default jquery"? And how do you know it's not added to the `<head>`?

Comment: I added the WP-provided jquery, I tried it on the header and then on the footer. But in both there was no change in the result, the plugin content does not work correctly

Comment: Be specific.  "Does not work correctly" gives no useful details and is impossible to troubleshoot

Comment: "Does not work correctly" Like I mentioned in my question `The htmls and src tags of the gallery images appear in the console, but the screen turns white in the location that should display the images`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. 
I forgot to put `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in my custom theme's `footer.php` file.

This was causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely things are one of these two things:

1. Your templates where you have installed your templates are not calling the content properly.  Shortcodes are expanded via a [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Referencewordpr) called [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content).  This filter is automatically applied when you use [the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) in your template.  **Note that using [get_the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) does NOT apply this filter, and the shortcodes will not be rendered**.
2. Your theme is somehow removing the `the_content` filter.  Do you have anything such as [remove_filter()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) running in your theme?

If you need further help, *edit your question and post your code, and expand on what you've checked / tested*.

**Since you have added your code**, I believe that your use of your own local jQuery is suspect, and could be causing the problem.  Remove your section of code that deregisters jquery and then registers your own version.

NOTE: Your code should look like this - be sure to enqueue jQuery, but leverage the built-in WP jQuery:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
} 

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_jquery');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I inserted in my question the `function.php` and `page.php` details

Comment: @Gislef - see the comment I added to your question about jQuery and how that's possibly causing the problem.

Comment: Finally found the solution, see my answer. Thank you for all your help @cale_b